# Incorrect Select Statement generated when using Guid as Primary Key in NHibernate 4

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I use the following code in LinqPad to demonstrate the problem:

```
void Main()
{
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
        .DataBaseIntegration(db =>
        {
            db.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=xxxxxxxx\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Testarossa;Integrated Security=True";
            db.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>();
        });

    /* Add the mapping we defined: */
    var mapper = new ModelMapper();
    mapper.AddMappings(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes());

    HbmMapping mapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();

    cfg.AddMapping(mapping);

    /* Create a session and execute a query: */
    using (ISessionFactory factory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory())
    using (ISession        session = factory.OpenSession())
    using (ITransaction    tx      = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        session.Get<Person>(2).Dump();
        session.Get<User>(new Guid("2952A2BB-DAFE-4221-A102-798A2EB12626")).Dump();

        tx.Commit();
    }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        this.Table("person");
        this.Id(p => p.Id);
        this.Property(p => p.FirstName);
        this.Property(p => p.LastName);
        this.Property(p => p.BirthDate);
    }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMapping<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        this.Table("user");

        this.Id(p => p.Id, id =>
        {
            id.Type(NHibernateUtil.Guid);
        });

        this.Property(p => p.FirstName);
        this.Property(p => p.LastName);
        this.Property(p => p.Created);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public virtual int      Id        { get; set; }
    public virtual string   FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string   LastName  { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public virtual Guid     Id        { get; set; }
    public virtual string   FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string   LastName  { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created   { get; set; }
}
```

The query for `Person` works well.  The query for `User` produced the following SQL:

```
SELECT userquery_0_.Id as Id11_0_, userquery_0_.FirstName as FirstName11_0_,
     userquery_0_.LastName as LastName11_0_, 
     userquery_0_.Created as Created11_0_ 
   FROM user userquery_0_ WHERE userquery_0_.Id=?
```

With the following error message:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
```

Well, I understand the reason for the SQL error, what I do not understand is, why is NHibernate generating this incorrect SQL statement.

Can someone please help out and explain?  Am I doing something wrong?

---

For convenience here the table ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE Testarossa.dbo.Person (
    Id        INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    FirstName NVARCHAR        NOT NULL,
    LastName  NVARCHAR        NOT NULL,
    BirthDate DATETIME DEFAULT (getdate())
);

CREATE TABLE Testarossa.dbo.[User] (
    Id        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    FirstName NVARCHAR                     NOT NULL,
    LastName  NVARCHAR                     NOT NULL,
    Created   DATETIME DEFAULT (getdate())
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word/name **`user`** is a keyword *(at least in SQL Server)*. So, such table name is ...

At least we should escape it like this

```
this.Table("[user]");
```

This style will work for SQL Server, general escape syntax for NHibernate is:

```
this.Table("`user`");
```

Comment: Obviously I did not understand the reason for the SQL error :-(  Long day...  Old eyes...  Thank you for pointing out!